# Angularjs directive conditional rendering without ng-if

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if, angularjs-compile

I have a directive which I render only if my authentication service tells me so:

```
<div my-loggedin-directive ng-if="security.isAuthenticated()"></div>
```

The directive itself is quite empty :

```
.directive('myLoggedinDirective', [
    function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'modules/myLoggedinDirective.tpl.html',
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            link: function($scope) {
                 $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                     console.log('$destroy');
                 });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Since my directive should be always rendered when I'm logged in, the ngIf logic should be inside the directive declaration, and not in a ng-if (the directive without the ngIf would be totally broken).

How can I change the directive code (injecting the test on the security service inside the directive declaration) knowing that I want the same behavior as the `ngIf` ? :

- directive present in the DOM only when `nfIf` resolves to `true`
- automatic calling of $destroy when `nfIf` resolve to `false`) ?

I tried to use `compile` function and a watcher to watch `security.isAuthenticated()` without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare extra directive attribute that will pass security object into your directive:

```
<div my-loggedin-directive my-security='security'></div>
```

And directive should include scope, make sure it uses two-way binding:

```
.directive('myLoggedinDirective', [
function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            security: "=mySecurity"
        }
        templateUrl: 'modules/myLoggedinDirective.tpl.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function($scope) {
             $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                 console.log('$destroy');
             });

             $scope.$watch('security', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                 if (newVal.isAuthenticated()) {
                 // do something
                 } else {
                 // do something
                 }
             });
        }
    };
}
```

]);

And now you can access $scope.security variable in your temple myLoggedinDirective.tpl.html

```
<div ng-if="security.isAuthenticated()">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me ;) I also injected service as a dependency to get rid of the extra attribute.